# Always get "undefined" returned when running query against text input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, parse-platform

JS code updated as per below comment. Now the alert box returns what is typed int eh input box, but I dont see it querying parse to see if that user exists.

```
var friendName;

    $('#friendsearch').on('keyup', function(e) {
       friendName = $(e.target).val();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("username", friendName);  // find users that match
    query.find({
    success: function(friend) {
    alert(friendName); 
      },
        error: function (error) {
     //Show if no user was found to match

     alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
         }

    });
    });
```

Using parse.com and the JavaScript SDK, this code should capture the input from the input box and then query it against existing users in the parse database.

It runs without issue, but the alert box is always returning "undefined" I'm presuming there is an issue with the "friendName" variable being set correctly?

I'm struggling to understand why this is, even using the debugger.

Any help, I'm thankful for.

url here http://kudosoo.com/findfriends.html?

```
  <form class="Find Friend">

        <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
        <input type="text" id="friendsearch" placeholder="Find Friend" class="input-field" required/> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login">Find</button> 
</form>




    <!-- Initialize the Parse object-->
    <script type="text/javascript">     
    Parse.initialize("xxx", "xxx");

var friendName;

$('#friendsearch').on('keyup', function(e) {
   friendName = $(e.target).val();
});

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", friendName);  // find users that match
query.find({
success: function(friend) {
alert(friendName); 
  },
    error: function (error) {
 //Show if no user was found to match

 alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
     }

});


 </script>
```

Comment: Try this   _friendName = $(this).val();_

Comment: Hi, thats what I started with and that does'nt work either. I have updated the question with a url

Comment: Why don't you set your logic inside keyup event? It looks like you are getting value before friendName is defined. `var friendName; alert(friendName);` returns undefined for sure

Comment: @A.Wolff I've updated the js code block on what I think you mean in the question. Is this correct?

Comment: @Dano007 Ya, that's what i was suggesting

Comment: @A.Wolff happy to accept the answer if you want to submit it, its solved this issue and created another one which I will address in another question I guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call ajax request inside input keyup event, to search for any specific value:

```
var friendName;

$('#friendsearch').on('keyup', function (e) {
    friendName = $(e.target).val();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("username", friendName); // find users that match
    query.find({
        success: function (friend) {
            alert(friendName);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            //Show if no user was found to match

            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }

    });
});
```